# Adding another condition to this conditional if statement

Tags: vb.net

I have this if statement right here:

```
If lbl1.Text <> "Good" Or lbl2.Text <> "Good" Or lbl3.Text <> "Good" Then
        MsgBox("Something.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

This works fine, but I also need to attach another condition to it, but for some reason I am drawing a blank on it. I need it to also pass that it is ok for lbl2 & lbl3 to be an empty string. In order words, if lbl1.text = "Good" then it is ok for lbl2 & lbl3 to be empty, therefore it will not exit sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a statement like this?

```
If Not ((lblA.Text = "Good" OrElse lblA.Text = String.Empty) AndAlso _
            (lblB.Text = "Good" OrElse lblB.Text = String.Empty) AndAlso _
            (lblC.Text = "Good" OrElse lblC.Text = String.Empty)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Something.")
    End If
```

Comment: Dropped the Exit Sub in there and this did what I needed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at it from the other way around, what you're saying is that **if any one of the labels says "Good", then don't enter this statement**, so, you could say **enter this statement if that is not the case**.

In other words:

```
If Not(lbl1.Text = "Good" Or lbl2.Text = "Good" Or lbl3.Text = "Good") Then
    MessageBox.Show("Something.")
End If
```

Hope that does the trick!

Comment: I always forget about If Not. I gotta get out of the habit of trying to fit the conditions with <>